# How can I remove all content between <pre> tags in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I've read and tried to implement variations on about 10 different solutions for this so far from stack overflow, and none of them are working. All I want to do is replace the content between two pre tags (including the tags themselves). I don't care if it's regex or straight up php. Anyone have any suggestions?

An example is:

```
This is how to remove pre tags and their contents:<br/>

<pre>
<?php>
[code here]
<?php>

That's all there is to it.
```

becomes:

```
This is how to remove pre tags and their contents:</br>
That's all there is to it.
```

This needs to happen before the html is rendered to the page.

I'm not sure DOMDocument will work. The context for my code is that it is happening within a plugin for expression engine (a codeigniter / php based CMS). The plugin truncates the html to a set character length, and renders that back to the parent template to be rendered in the browser - so the domdocument can't render to the browser - it just needs to return the code to the parent template with the  tags and content removed.

Comment: Certainly not with regex. Try [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: [_Never_ with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  And straight PHP will be worse.

Comment: Parsing HTML is not a job for regular expressions.  Here's why: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html  Please look at http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of the right way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `</pre>` tag somewhere in your example? When you say that the HTML is truncated, do you mean this is happening before your code gets it, so it might not have be properly balanced tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex will work fine if you use assertions (ie lookahead/lookbehind). This should remove anything within pre tags:

```
$page_content = preg_replace('/<(pre)(?:(?!<\/\1).)*?<\/\1>/s','',$page_content);
```

If you want to include other tags, just add them to the initial matching group like:

```
(pre|script|style)
```

the only real issue with regex tag removal is nested tags of the same type, like:

```
<div>
    <div>inner closing tag might match beginning outer opening div tag leaving an orphan outer closing tag</div>
<div>
```

**Edit**

I tested the example you left in the other comment on the other answer, works fine for me:

```
$html = 'This is a quick snippet that often comes in handy: <pre>[code]blah blah[/code]</pre>';
$html = preg_replace('/<(pre)(?:(?!<\/?\1).)*?<\/\1>/s',"",$html);
var_dump($html);
```

result:

```
string(51) "This is a quick snippet that often comes in handy: "
```

Comment: This didn't remove anything for me.

Comment: does your code have a closing </pre> tag? the above example doesn't appear to... this regex needs a closing tag to match everything in-between and including open and closing tags.

Comment: ok good, I was starting to wonder if there was an issue with your pcre or php settings

Answer (score 2):

Use `DOMDocument`:

```
$html = '<div id="container">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <pre>
        content
    </pre>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//div[@id="container"]/pre';
// $query = '//pre'; // for all <pre>
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($entries as $one){
    $newelement = $dom->createTextNode('Some new node!'); 
    $one->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $one);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/O0CymAMJ)

Comment: This looks like an awesome way to do it, but I get this warning: `Message: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Extra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 4`

Comment: Also, this is functioning inside a file which handles the placement of the revised html content itself, so I don't want to render the replacement content to the DOM. Does this still work?

Comment: It should work without any problems, as long as the `$string` is a HTML string.

Comment: By $string I'm assuming you mean $html? My $html variable would look like this: `'This is a quick snippet that often comes in handy: <pre>[code]blah blah[/code]</pre>`

Comment: Sorry, I had to go someplace. You could have added a custom tag to wrap all text: http://codepad.org/MzVETYaq